# Sorting 2 list of dictionaries by comparing keys without white space

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dictionaries that I would like to sort according to the first list.

```
target_dict_list = [{' J ane Mom' : 22}, {'James Dad': 25}, {'Jan e Mom': 35}]
new_dict_list = [{'Jam es Dad': 25}, {'Jan e Mom': 22}, {'Jane M om': 35}, {'Jayson kid': 30}]
```

Output of the second list after sorting

```
new_dict_list = [{'Jan e Mom':22}, {'Jam es Dad': 25}, {'Jane M om': 35}, {'Jayson kid': 30}]
```

Comment: you could use `str.replace(' ', '')` on the keys as you loop through them.

Comment: But without spaces, in your output "Jam es Dad" should come before "Jan e Mom", "m" before "n".

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to compare elements without space and to match the order from `target_dict_list`:

```
target_dict_list = [{' J ane Mom': 22}, {'James Dad': 25}, {'Jan e Mom': 35}]
new_dict_list = [{'Jam es Dad': 25}, {'Jan e Mom': 22}, {'Jane M om': 35}, {'Jayson kid': 30}]

# Result list starts as a copy of target list
result_list = target_dict_list.copy()

# Search each element from new list into the target list
for item_idx, item in enumerate(new_dict_list):
    found_item = False
    for target_idx, target_item in enumerate(target_dict_list):

        # Extract key and value from item and target_item
        (key_new, val_new), = item.items()
        (key_target, val_target), = target_item.items()

        # Compare keys without space and also values
        if ''.join(key_new.split(' ')) == ''.join(key_target.split(' ')) and val_new == val_target:
            # Replace corresponding item from result list with one from new list
            result_list[target_idx] = item
            found_item = True
            break

    if found_item:
        continue
    else:
        result_list.append(item)

print('Target list: ', target_dict_list)
print('New list: ', new_dict_list)
print('Result list: ', result_list)
```